# jQuery - Alert Based on JSON Response Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I need to display an alert based on occurrence of string in a JSON response.
Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: dataString2,
    data: dataString,
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('' + Username + '' + ":" + '' + Password + '')
    },
    success: function(jqXHR) {
        if (jqXHR.responseJSON('ok')) {
            alert('First Real Server Configured');
        }
    },
    statusCode: {
        406 : function() {
            alert('There is an unexpected string in your data.\nFix the error and try again.');
        },
        401 : function() {
            alert('Wrong username or password.');
        }
    },
});
});
```

Here is the JSON response:

```
{
     "status":"ok"
}
```

HTTP response code is "200 OK", and the server is responding with Content-Type:application/json

When using the above code, I get:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Any idea?

Comment: Ok, what exactly is "not a function"? Which line?

Comment: what part of your code is undefined?

Comment: `jqXHR` would be the response , would not have `responseJSON` property. To access `jqXHR` object , include `(data, textStatus, jqXHR)` at `success` , then access `responseJSON` at `jqXHR.responseJSON` - without `("ok")`

Comment: @Juhana,
The following:
if (jqXHR.responseJSON('ok')) {

Comment: @Guest271314
But I need to display the alert only if the string "ok" is present in the response data.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "/echo/json/",
    data: {json:JSON.stringify({status:"ok"})},
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " 
        + btoa('' + "Username" + '' + ":" + '' + "Password" + '')
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // check `jqXHR.responseJSON` here
        if (jqXHR.responseJSON.status === "ok") {
            alert('First Real Server Configured');
        }
    },
    statusCode: {
        406 : function() {
            alert('There is an unexpected string in your data.'
                 + '\nFix the error and try again.');
        },
        401 : function() {
            alert('Wrong username or password.');
        }
    }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ca9aa04r/

Comment: It seems that when I use string that is different than "ok" (but still is part of the response data), the alert doesn't popup.

For instance, my server response is:

`{
  "status":"err",
  "message":"Alteon cannot create the specified new entry. An entry with the same specifications already exists."
}`

When I use:
`
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // check `jqXHR.responseJSON` here
        if (jqXHR.responseJSON.status === "already exists") {
            alert('Real Server Already Exists');
        }
    },

The alert is not displayed.

Comment: @UdiDahan If possible, can create stacksnippets / fork jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ca9aa04r/ , with included `js` , to demonstrate ?

Comment: You can see in the link that I used if `jqXHR.responseJSON.data` 
But I also tried `jqXHR.responseJSON.status` like you wrote, and it didn't work.

Comment: See `console` at jsfiddle _"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) => fiddle.jshell.net/yym93j7y/show/alteon1.js "_  Can post full `url` of `alteon1.js` ?

Comment: It's currently located locally on my PC, so it is a bit of an issue.
It seems that it pops up the first alert, no matter what I'm writing in the jqXHR.responseJSON.data.

I wrote jqXHR.responseJSON.data = 'bla', and it still pops up the alert (while I can assure you that there is no "bla" string in the response data).

Comment: `=` sets / defines, `===` provides strict comparison . Try including text of `alteon1.js` at jsfiddle

Comment: I included the full alteon1.js and the full HTML here:
http://jsfiddle.net/8a8co28k/

Just be advised that I'm not looking for a strict comparison (=== operator) but I actually want to search response contains a string.

For instance, if the following response:

{
     "status":"ok"
}

Contains the string "ok".

Comment: Any idea guys?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
$.ajax({
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        url: dataString2,
                                        data: dataString,
                                        contentType: 'application/json',
                                        headers: {
                                            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('' + Username + '' + ":" + '' + Password + '')
                                        },
                                        success: function(data) {
                                                status = data.status;
                                                message = data.message;
                                                if (status === 'ok') {
                                                alert("First Real Server Configured Successfully");
                                                }
                                                if (status === 'err') {
                                                alert(message);
                                                }
                                            },
                                        statusCode: {
                                            406 : function() {
                                                alert('There is an unexpected string in your data.\nFix the error and try again.');
                                            },
                                            401 : function() {
                                                alert('Wrong username or password.');
                                            }
                                            },
                                });
```

Source:
[$.jquery ajax returned data (json) displays as 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046010/jquery-ajax-returned-data-json-displays-as-undefined)

Thank you all for your assistance!